# IIdentity.Name versus IIdentity.GetUserName() extension method

Tags: asp.net-identity

The extension method is in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`. So what's the difference? When will these 2 return different values?

```
var idName = User.Identity.Name;
var idGetName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The implementation of the extension method is something like;

```
public static string GetUserName(this IIdentity identity)
{
    if (identity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
    }
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if (claimsIdentity == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return claimsIdentity.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name");
}
```

The only apparent difference in return value between `IIdentity.Name` and `IdentityExtensions.GetUserName()` is that `GetUserName()` *always returns null if the underlying IIdentity implementation is not a `ClaimsIdentity`*, while the `Name` property will return whatever the underlying IIdentity implementation returns.